# Как бы я её ни/не поддерживал, а ей, по-видимому, не нужен никакой support

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Как бы я её ни/не поддерживал, **а** ей, по-видимому, не нужен никакой support.

Comment: Верно с НИ, поскольку это усиление утверждения. В школе даже проходят это.